# Counter clock on different page is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, timer

I an a newbie to JS and We created a code for clock that start from end time when reload a same page or moves to next page But this is not working properly. I am showing javascript code of that here . We are adding this to limesurvey js file.

Js code:

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(window.location.href) || [null, ''])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20')) || null;
```

}

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var start = Date.now(),
        diff,
        minutes,
        seconds;
    function timer() {
        // get the number of seconds that have elapsed since 

        diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

        // does the same job as parseInt truncates the float
        minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
        seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds ; 

        if (diff <= 0) {

            display.textContent ="Time finished ";
            alert("Time is over.Click ok to submit Exam.")
            $("#movesubmitbtn").click();
            clearInterval(handle);
        }
    }
    // we don't want to wait a full second before the timer starts
    timer();
    var handle = setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

window.onload = function(){
    //set cookie if not exist
    if(document.cookie && document.cookie.match('examDuration')){
        examTime = document.cookie.match(/(^|;)examDuration=([^;]+)/)[2];
    }
    else{
        timeLimit = getURLParameter('examTime');
        document.cookie = 'examDuration='+ 60*timeLimit + '; path=/; ' ;
        examTime= 60*timeLimit ;
    }

    var display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(examTime, display);

    $("#movenextbtn").onclick(function(){
        remainingTime = (minutes * 60) + seconds ;
        document.cookie = 'examDuration='+ remainingTime + '; path=/; ' ;
        clearInterval(handle);
    });
    $("#movesubmitbtn").onclick(function(){
        remainingTime = (minutes * 60) + seconds ;
        document.cookie = 'examDuration='+ remainingTime + '; path=/; ' ; 
        clearInterval(handle);
    });
};
```

I don't know why it is not working. I have included JS library link in header of that and have taken all necessary steps were needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: in my opinion , Cookie portion is not working properly .can anyone help in this. thanks